# не работает slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Почему не работает слик слайдер? Сделал вроде все по инструкции? 
Вот ошибка
[image: ошибка в консоли]

Вот index.php

```html
<?php 
 session_start();
 ob_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick-theme.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">


 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,900&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>shop</title>
</head>
<body>

 <header id="header">
  <?php 

   include "pages/header.php";

   ?>
 </header>

 <section id="content">
  <div class="left_content">
   <div class="left_content_catalog_sidebar">
    <?php 

     include "elems/left_catalog.php";

     ?>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top_content">
   <?php 

    include "elems/top_slider.php";
    include "elems/top_sales.php";
    include "elems/top_sale.php";

    ?>
  </div>
 </section>

 <footer id="footer">
  <?php 

   include "pages/footer.php";

   ?>
 </footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub > a').click(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
         $('.sub ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }
        return false;
    });
         $('.mini-menu > ul > li > a').click(function(){
      $('.mini-menu > ul > li > a, .sub a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }),
         $('.sub ul li a').click(function(){
      $('.sub ul li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот файл со слайдером (top_slider.php)

```html
<div class="slider_slick_items">
    <div class="top_content_slider">
        <div class="slider_description">
            <div class="top_content_description_head">
                <h3 class="top_content_description_header">Электрический мини-вертолет Beacon</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="top_content_description_characteristic">
                <p>Тип: мини вертолет</p>
                <p>Шасси: пластик</p>
                <p>Электродвигатели: 180 размера (2шт.)</p>
                <p>Время полета: 10 - 12 минут</p>
            </div>
            <div class="top_content_description_price">
                <p>Цена 6 960 рублей</p>
                <form action="">
                    <input class="in_cart_btn" type="submit" name="in_cart" value="В корзину">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider_description_img">
            <img src="img/pic.png" alt="вертолет">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top_content_slider">
        <div class="slider_description">
            <div class="top_content_description_head">
                <h3 class="top_content_description_header">Электрический мини-вертолет Beacon</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="top_content_description_characteristic">
                <p>Тип: мини вертолет</p>
                <p>Шасси: пластик</p>
                <p>Электродвигатели: 180 размера (2шт.)</p>
                <p>Время полета: 10 - 12 минут</p>
            </div>
            <div class="top_content_description_price">
                <p>Цена 6 960 рублей</p>
                <form action="">
                    <input class="in_cart_btn" type="submit" name="in_cart" value="В корзину">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider_description_img">
            <img src="img/pic.png" alt="вертолет">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот главный main.js файл

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.slider_slick_items').slick();
});
```

Вот структура папок (вдруг с путями намудрил что).
[image: корневая папка]

[image: Папка CSS]

[image: Папка js]

Comment: Зачем вы два раза jquery подключаете? Плюс у вас почему то скрипт вынесен в html структуру и из-за этого два раза прописывается document ready

Comment: хз... но ваш ответ помог)) Убрал лишнее )) Можете отвечать, поставлю галочку)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы два раза подключаете jquery, плюс старайтесь писать все свои скрипты в одном файле, а не выносить их в html структуру, из-за этого у вас два раза прописано document ready, от этого и идут конфликты в коде.

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать `document ready` несколько раз?

Comment: В данном случае это не зачем, зачем вообще выносить подобный код отдельно в html и оборачивать его в document ready? Когда есть уже созданный файл js и там есть своя проверка document ready